# Document schema - Performance vs Modification anomaly - tradeoff

Tags: mongodb, database-design, database-schema, normalization, rdbms

> TO design a document schema for below application.
>
> ### [image]

---

One approach is, below MongoDB document designed **primarily** based on the matching of data access pattern of an application (above).

```
> db.posts.find().pretty()
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5099f5eabcf1bf2d90ea41ad"), // post 1
    "author": "xyz",
    "body" : "This is a test body",
    "comments": [
            {
                "body": "this is a comment",
                "email": "alan@tech.com",
                "author": "Alan Donald"
            },
            {
                "body": "this is another comment\r\n",
                "email": "alan@tech.com",
                "author": "Alan Donald"

            }           
            ],
    "date" : ISODate("2012-11-07T05:47:22,9412"),
    "permalink": "This_is_a_test_Post",
    "tags":[
        "cycling",
        "mongodb",
        "swimming"  
     ],
    "title": "This is a test post"
}
```

Above schema allow application data access pattern, to,

1) collect the most recent blog entries for blog home page

2) Collect all the information to display a single post

3) Collect all comments by single author

but not,

providing table of contents by tag

---

Another approach is, document schema, with relational approach inclination would look like,

```
> db.posts.find().pretty()
{
    "_id": "Post1", // use ObjectId BSON type
    "title": "This is a test post",
    "body": "This is a test body",
    "date": ISODate("2012-11-07T05:47:22,9412")

}

> db.comments.find().pretty()
{
    "_id": 3, // use ObjectId BSON type
    "post_id": "Post1",
    "author": "Alan Donald",
    "author_email": "alan@tech.com",
    "nth": 0
    "body": "this is a comment"
},
{
    "_id": 4, // use ObjectId BSON type
    "post_id": "Post1",
    "author": "Alan Donald",
    "author_email": "alan@tech.com",
    "nth": 1,
    "body": "this is another comment\r\n"
},

> db.tags.find().pretty()
{
    "_id": 5, // use ObjectId BSON type
    "tag": "cycling"
    "post_id": "Post1"
},
{
    "_id": 6, // use ObjectId BSON type
    "tag": "mongodb"
    "post_id": "Post1"
},
{
    "_id": 7, // use ObjectId BSON type
    "tag": "swimming"
    "post_id": "Post1"
}
```

---

**Comparison:**

1) MongoDB does not inherently support join operation among collections. So, approach1 looks better. Because approach2 would require multiple queries and join on the results of those multiple query.

2) Approach1 looks better with embedding(pre-join) of `comments` in a document, that keeps data consistent, even though MongoDB lacks foreign key constraint.

3) MongoDB does not support transactions but support atomic operation at single document level. So, approach1 looks better

---

*post* and *comments* have one-to-many relation. *Many* would be large or few.

**Question:**

Using approach1, each document(post) from `db.posts` collection consists of multiple `comments` with redundant data. Enhances performace but prone to modification anomaly. Is there a better approach for schema design?

Answer (score 1):

In approach 1 for comment, you are using an array which has a limitation in MongoDB.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits

And from `Mongodb 3.2` onwards in aggregation pipeline you can use `$lookup` for the join.

Comment: When you refer to `$lookup` for join, Are you recommending second approach?

Comment: Yes, because in the first approach if your array size crosses the threshold limit.
Then it will be problematic.

Comment: You mean, 16MB limit of a document?

Comment: Yes, If you are sure that the limit can't be crossed by your application then approach 1 is ok.
And in approach 2 there is no need to put the tag in a separate collection.

Comment: But, I learnt [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mvfb1CbXp1Q&index=2&list=PLffUyEIMenSnRVQGxRVphq-HelRrSIdzh), that the single most important factor in designing the application's database schema with MongoDB is about, matching the data access patterns of your application. Are we not breaking that in approach 2?

Comment: As I said approach 1 is good, keeping all data in a single document.
But I feel that approach 2 give you the flexibility of putting large no of documents in the different collection and refer that collection in parent collection.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152367/discussion-between-ayush-mittal-and-overexchange).